Can I listen for field assignments on a given object using ByteBuddy / ASM?
Given the following object
public class MyBean
   private String name;

   public String getName() { 
      return this.name; 
   }

   public void setName(String name) {
      // can I somehow get a notification when name is assigned a new value?
      this.name = name; 
   }
}

Can I manipulate the byte code of MyBean at runtime such that I can notify a listener whenever MyBean.name is assigned a new value?

This looks like an XY Problem. How about just adding some code in the setters to call the listener? If you can't do that, please provide more context.

I'm writing a swing based UI framework where UI controls (JTextBox, JList) etc are mapped to bean properties. If the bean property is changed, I want to change the UI control (JTextField etc) and vice versa. I don't want to force this boilerplate to be written for every bean. I want to use bytebuddy/ASM to enhance any bean that is mapped to a UI control. I want to do similar to what svelte does

Sounds like you could use annotation processing to add the boilerplate code.

I'd prefer to instrument the classes. It's possible the beans come from a third party jar and I can't edit the sources (eg add annotations) to make them work for the UI

You cannot change the code in a class after it is loaded. You can generate a new class and load that, but it won't be the same class. The object you are given won't suddenly change its type to the new class. You can create an instance of the new class and mandate that all changes should be made on this instance instead, but in any case it won't be pretty.

It's possible I can use a custom classloader for the UI framework

Okay, that's good to know. So you won't be doing this "at runtime", but at load time.

At the moment I'm just trying to get a feel for what's possible. I'll need to scan through the UI components (java classes & xml's) to know which beans I need to instrument (eg which bean properties mapped to UI controls). Hopefully I can see this meta information before "loading" the bean classses. Perhaps the scanning will need to be done in a separate classloader? Then I can load the UI components with the dynamic/instrumenting classloader?

This sounds like a typical AspectJ use case, but of course you can also implement this with Byte Buddy or similar tools.

It is certainly possible, it's a basic use case. Have you made an attempt?

Is there some sample code showing how I can find all assignments of a given field to add my "notify listener" logic?
